# Using a Select SUM statement with joins

Tags: sql

Someone has written the following stored proc query (I have removed all the irrelevant code to make things easier to read)

```
 SELECT           
   CRL.ClientNum ,    
            ..."A lot of columns"...,
   ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM db..History dh (nolock) WHERE dh.id = dd.Id AND ActivityId = 11), 0.00) AS [Some Amt],    
            ..."A lot more columns"...        
   FROM db..[SomeLog] SL  
            ..."A lot of inner joins and left joins"...             
   where clause
   order by clause
```

This all okay but, now I need to put in a Case statement to select/compare columns from The "db..History" table. The issue is there is no existing join on this table.

- I have tried putting in an inner join on the "db..History" table but this returns a lot more rows than it should. Most likely because there are multiple "Histories" for the table its joining on.
- I thought about using a temp table at the start to store the "db..History" table values but this required doing a lot of inner joins to get the data and would be performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your inner join isn't correct, however, you can [create a view](http://programming4.us/database/3850.aspx) of your necessary tables & fields and implement a join on that. in most situation using visual tools(shown in the above link) to create a view is easier and better than writing code.

Most join problems are because of creating tables incorrectly. If you create tables distributed truly and clear, it can help you a lot.

Comment: Turns out I did have add a couple more conditions on the new left join I created for the history table